# click function is triggring Event even when parameter is mismatched

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am having a button ,which trigres a function called check (resp is a refrence in my html template)

```
<button
(click)="check(resp)">
clickMe
</button>
```

in ts code i am having

```
check() {
console.log("check is clicked")
}
```

I  can see my console output

But i am confused why check(Function) is called  successfully, i am not expecting any argument in ts code but my template code passed an arg , i am expecting an signature mismatch error , why it is able to call successfully ?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript enforces type checking at design time, not run time. The HTML template is not part of the .ts file, so it does not get compiled. Because it does not get compiled, the Typescript compiler does not see it. When the app runs, its standard JS, which does not enforce type checking.

Comment: i am  not confused with the type check confused ,about the parameters it takes

Comment: As we know typescript becomes javascript in browser
and javascript is runtime script it 
in programming languages there is concept of varargs(covariance) argument is overriding.
so this explains your script behaviour